# Multiple %s with list/tuple in Python

Tags: python, tuples, fwrite

I am trying to output the same string from a list/tuple to different %s, I tried using this:

```
A = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
# A = list(('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
print type(A)
output = open('output.txt', 'w')
output.writelines('Multiple outputs like %s and %s\n' % (f for f in A, f for f in A))
output.close()
```

How is it done in Python?

But it produces a syntax error. I need an output of the form:

```
Multiple outputs like A and A
Multiple outputs like B and B
Multiple outputs like C and C
Multiple outputs like D and D
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
output.writelines(('Multiple outputs like %s and %s\n' % (f,f)) for f in A)
```

Answer (score 1):

The most Pythonic way to do this is by using `output.writelines()` and `string.format()` function:

```
output.writelines(('Multiple outputs like {word} and {word}\n'.format(word=w) for w in A))
```

Answer (score 0):

I might do something like:

```
output.writelines(('Multiple outputs like %s and %s\n' % t for t in zip(A, B))
```

Here I've assumed that you don't actually want the same value twice (otherwise, see the answer by @Petter) but have a separate iterable `B` that you would like to see "paired" with `A` in the output.